# mysqli - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, syntax-error

I am continuosly getting this error:

`Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

I don't know why is this happening and none of the preivous questions are helping.

**This is my code:**

**User.php**

```
public static function GetUserFullName($username){
    if(Utilities::IsValid($username)){
        $username = Utilities::SafeString($username);

        Database::OpenConnection();
        $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT Name FROM user WHERE Username = ?") or die(Database::$databaseConnection->error);

        $query->bind_param("s", $username);
        $result = $query->execute();

        Database::CloseConnection();
        if($result){

            $query->bind_result($name);
            $query->fetch();
            $query->close();
            return $name;
        }
    }else return -1;
}
```

**Skill.php**

```
public static function UpdateSkills($id, $skill, $action){
    if(Utilities::IsValid($id) && Utilities::IsValid($skill) && Utilities::IsValid($action)){
        $id = Utilities::SafeString($id);
        $skill = Utilities::SafeString($skill);
        $action = Utilities::SafeString($action);
        Database::OpenConnection();

        if($action == 'i'){
            $skill = str_replace(" ", "", $skill);
            $db = Database::$databaseConnection;
            $skills = explode(",", $skill);
            $query = "";
            foreach ($skills as $s){
                $query .= "INSERT INTO skill (User_ID,Skill) VALUES({$id},'{$s}');";
            }
            $result = $db->multi_query($query);
            echo $db->error;
            Database::CloseConnection();

            if($result) return 1;
            else return -1;
        }else if($action == 'd'){
            $query = Database::$databaseConnection->prepare("DELETE FROM Skill WHERE Skill = ? AND User_ID = ?");
            $query->bind_param("si", $skill,$id);
            $result = $query->execute();
            Database::CloseConnection();
            if($result && $query->num_rows >0) return 1;
            else return -1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/UserLogin.php';
require_once 'Classes/User.php';
$user_fullname = User::GetUserFullName($_SESSION["username"]);
?>
<header>
    <div class="welcome_area">
        <p>
            Welcome, <b><a href="profile.php" style="text-decoration: underline !important;"><?php echo $user_fullname; ?></a> </b>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a>
                    <ul>

                        <li><div><a href="#">My Questions</a></div>
                        </li>                       
                        <li><div><a href="#">Settings</a></div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><div><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="inbox.php">Inbox</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Notifications</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<section id="container">
    <br />
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="content">
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
require_once "Classes/User.php";
require_once "Classes/Skill.php";
require_once "Classes/UserLogin.php";
if(!UserLogin::IsLoggedIn("username")) header("location: login.php");
$user_details = User::GetUserDetails($_SESSION["username"]);
echo Skill::UpdateSkills(11, "programmer,designer", "i");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Help Exchange</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/user.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/widgets.css" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/profile.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var user_details = eval(<?php echo $user_details; ?>);
        var about = user_details.About;
    </script>
    <?php require_once 'admin/header.php';?>
```

***Please help me :'(***

Comment: "Commands out of sync" seems to mean that you're trying to do things that aren't doable at that time.  (The typical example is trying to do another query without dealing with the result(s) you got back from the previous one.)

Comment: What line does the error appear on?  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: did you try freeing the results from a previous query before doing another select?

Comment: no luck at all! @cHao

Comment: no luck at all @roninblade

Comment: just saying "no luck" isn't really helping. you need to be more descriptive. what did you do, what was the result, was there any errors, etc etc

Comment: I tried using `free_result()`, that didn't helped, error came the same. That'sit :) @roninblade

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32837401/2096041